# Configuration of iOS Application for iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, xcode

I have set up the iOS development target for my iOS application to be 13.6, so do I need to configure my app for iPhone 4s as well?

Comment: iOS 13 is only available for iPhone 6s and later, so your app will not be available to iPhone 4s users (or 5 or 5s or 6)